# android - How to search in xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

i have a XML file in : /res/xml/countries.xml

and also i have a view with editText inside.

i want to search that text (users should type in editText) in my countries.xml file!

here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <countries>
     <country>
       <name>United State</name>
     </country>
  <countries>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a whole document, use `XML Parser`, like [Pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283586/android-how-to-search-in-xml-file/20283845#20283665) already mentioned. If you only want to pick out only one or few certain things, I would suggest `XPath`. [Here is a good Tutorial on how to use XPath in Java.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explain clearly how to parse an XML file : [XML parser](http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/)

Other tutorial simpler with XPath : [Xparse tutorial](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-using-xpath/)

Comment: i can't understand these guides please help me with easier guides

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse that xml file containing the countries name. Store list of countries in any arraylist and then write any search algo to search the text found from that edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath [tutorial](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-using-xpath/)...
You will have good learning experience...